# How can i make macros take first row in csv file

Tags: csv, imacros

How can i make macros take first row in txt file (links.txt) while macros loops through file pages.csv and after macros start to loop it again(pages.csv), i need to take second row from file (links.txt) Here is my macros..

```
SET !DATASOURCE pages.csv
SET linesInFile 35
SET !LOOP 1
SET innerLoop EVAL("var i = \"{{!LOOP}}\" % \"{{linesInFile}}\"; (i == 0) ? \"{{linesInFile}}\" : i;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{innerLoop}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"kqa es"
SET !DATASOURCE links.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div[class=\"df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable\"]" CHARS={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"d-k-l b-c b-c-Ba qy jt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following hint with use of a “fixed” loop:

```
' ...
SET !DATASOURCE links.txt
SET fixedLoop EVAL("Math.floor(('{{!LOOP}}' - 1)/'{{linesInFile}}') + 1;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{fixedLoop}}
' ...
```